# How to add another Gtk::Box in Gtkmm C++

Tags: c++, linux, gtk3, gtkmm

I want to add another Box to my window in the Gtk example, so that I can put other elements below menu.

Here is the link to example:

[12.4.1. Main Menu example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.8/sec-menus-examples.html.en)

I have searched for it, but found HBox/Vbox, but in the example, there is Box declared, with `Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL`

How do I add a simple element like lable or button below the menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a Box whose Orientation is set to Vertical and you can easily add other elements like buttons and labels to it.
So add a button below the menubar as following:

```
Gtk::Widget* pMenubar = m_refUIManager->get_widget("/MenuBar");
if(pMenubar)
    m_Box.pack_start(*pMenubar, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

Gtk::Button* pButton = new Gtk::Button(Gtk::Stock::OK);
m_Box.pack_start(*pButton, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

show_all_children();
```

P.S: For a better visualization I'd recommend using Glade to see how it should look, what should go where, how packing is done. And then you can easily do the same in your C++ code.